# Android Room Compilation error suspend function @Transaction

Tags: android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm having problems with suspend function in Room @Transaction

Versions:

```
room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

I also tried with 2.1.0-rc01.

Kotlin : 1.3

This is my DAO interface:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(sifrBl: SifrBl)

@Query("DELETE FROM sifrbl")
suspend fun deleteAll()

@Transaction
suspend fun setSifrBl(sifrBl: SifrBl){
    deleteAll()
    insert(sifrBl)
}
```

At compilation I get following error:

```
Method annotated with @Transaction must not return deferred/async return type androidx.lifecycle.LiveData. Since transactions are thread confined and Room cannot guarantee that all queries in the method implementation are performed on the same thread, only synchronous @Transaction implemented methods are allowed. If a transaction is started and a change of thread is done and waited upon then a database deadlock can occur if the additional thread attempts to perform a query. This restrictions prevents such situation from occurring.
```

I'm referring to [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5)

If I remove suspend in all functions then it works.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: show us your dependencies

Comment: Not sure what dependencies you're looking for. Wrote those related to Room and Coroutines.

Comment: try changin the room version to `2.1.0-rc01`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was something wrong with dependencies.

```
room_version = "2.1.0-rc01"

    //Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

// Test helpers
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

Now it works.

Comment: You saved my life man. The transactions weren't working without the correct dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I had to make the method open and then it worked. Checking the generated class, I can see why it's necessary to make the method open since it is overridden in the generated class.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code of the annotation processor I can say it is impossible for the given code to produce the stated error, since it would only trigger if the method was returning a `LiveData<*>` object. ([reference](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/633c84b26612914f9799d3dddfea5467afa36232/room/compiler/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/processor/TransactionMethodProcessor.kt#L52))

For reference, any `@Transaction` method which in some way returns a `LiveData` object, an RxJava object or Guava's `ListenableFuture` object would trigger this exception since they may cause mutations after returning from the method. Note that this is a blacklist and any object that defers execution would be equally problematic, but would not trigger an error.